# geth account new - password on command line

Tags: go, ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I'm trying to use a password on the command line instead of keeping it  on a text file using `geth`:

```
geth --password mYp@ssw0rd account new
```

but the above throws:

> Fatal: Failed to read password file: open mYp@ssw0rd: no such file or
>   directory

Which makes sense since `--password` expects a "*Password file to use for non-inteactive password input*".
**Is there any way to provide the password directly on the command line using `geth`?**
Something like:

```
geth --password mYp@ssw0rd account new
```

I've seen an  [article on go-ethereum wiki](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options#sample-usage-in-testing-environment) using:

```
geth --password <(echo -n mYp@ssw0rd) account new
```

But this throws another error on CentOS:

> -sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to create your account from command line.

```
geth account new --password <(echo $mypassword)
geth account new --password [arg]
```

`[arg]` = the name of a file containing the password and not the password itself.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to start your network in one window of PowerShell (if using windows)
and then, in a new PowerShell window, execute

```
geth attach
```

and then use management APIs for various purposes, like:

```
> personal.newAccount()
Passphrase:                      //Type password here
Repeat passphrase:
<addressOfNewAccount>
```

or

```
> personal.newAccount("PasswordHere")
<addressOfNewAccount>
```

Here is the link to know more about [management APIs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs)